# Error showed by SQL server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, subquery

```
set @return=(SELECT u_id,u_pass from m_User where u_id = @userName AND u_pass=@userPass);
```

shows error something like this

```
"Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS."
```

Comment: Data type of @return?

Comment: You can `SET` only one value. `@return` can't have multiple values. You are trying to assign multiple values with `SELECT u_id, u_pass`. That's why you are getting the error message. Try assigning a single value. If you want multiple values, use a `TABLE` type instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can not select multiple columns in sub query.
here you are selecting two columns `u_id,u_pass`.

select only one as required.

**if @return is of data type (like, varchar,int)**

```
set @return=(SELECT u_id from m_User where u_id = @userName AND u_pass=@userPass);
```

**or**

```
set @return=(SELECT u_pass from m_User where u_id = @userName AND u_pass=@userPass);
```